# Checking for nil result set before viewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been reading [Checking for nil in view in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749157/checking-for-nil-in-view-in-ruby-on-rails) but I'm struggling to implement the marked solution.

I want to only load a graph in my View if a result set is not `nil`.

Controller:

```
  @statistics = # ...my ActiveRecord query...
```

Helper:

```
 def show_stats(statistics)
     if statistics.pluck(:count)
       image_tag(Gchart.line :size => '640x260',
         :stacked => false,
         :title => '',
         :data => [statistics.pluck(:count)],
         :legend => ['Stats'],
         :bar_colors => ['3300CC', '3399FF'],
         :axis_with_labels => ['y'])
     end
 end
```

View (HAML):

```
= show_stats(@statistics)
```

Currently when there are no statistics, I get an error.  I want the View to not render the graph if there are no statistics.  What am I doing wrong in the helper?

Error:

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

on the line where I call the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly `statistics.pluck(:count)` will always return an array consisting of values of `count` attribute for each record found.

in ruby empty array evaluates to `true`, you might try to rewrite that `if` line like this:

```
if statistics.pluck(:count).any?
```

in fact it's good idea to cache that value and not fetch it from db again few lines below:

```
if (counts = statistics.pluck(:count)).any?
  ...
  :data => [counts]
  ...
end
```

also i assume `:data` option wants array of values and not array of array of values so the final version would be:

```
if (counts = statistics.pluck(:count)).any?
  ...
  :data => counts
  ...
end
```

P.S. if you still have an error - please share a full backtrace with us, knowing only "undefined method" doesn't tell much

Answer (score 1):

Why not check for `@statistics` in your view like follows:

```
= show_stats(@statistics) if @statistics
```

Comment: if @statistics was nil the error would be undefined method `pluck'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
= show_stats(@statistics) unless @statistics.nil?
```